# Eclipse doesn't recognise git-based project

Tags: eclipse, git, cmake

I've cloned a git cmake project to a directory `sourcedir`. I created a `.project` file with

```
cd build 
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug sourcedir
```

I then imported the project in eclipse, which works fine. The source files are in a folder in the project explorer called `[Source directory]`. But how can I get Eclipse to recognise the project as a git-based project?

I can see my repository with `Window -> show view -> Other -> Git -> Git Repositories`, but it doesn't seem to be linked to the files in `[Source directory]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `File > import` can you select `git > projects from git`? This will automatically link the project to the git repo.

Comment: The problem was that the project I created not purely git-controlled sources, but already build-specific. I created a second project now from the git repo, that is linked. Thanks!